# Change total_fields limit for Elasticsearch index using node.js client

Tags: javascript, node.js, elasticsearch, indexing

I'm using node.js Elasticsearch 7.17 client to create default index settings, and I'd like the [total_fields limit](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.17/mapping-settings-limit.html) to be more than the default 1000.  When I try the following:

```
export const defaultCaseIndexSettings: IndicesIndexSettings = {
  'index.number_of_replicas': 0,
  'index.number_of_shards': 6,
  'index.max_result_window': Number(INDEX_MAX_RESULT_WINDOW),
  'index.mapping.total_fields.limit': 10000,
etc.
}
```

it seems that `index.mapping.total_fields.limit` is not a setting that can be set on `IndicesIndexSettings`.  I've also tried:

```
export const defaultCaseSettingsIndexConfig: IndicesCreateRequest['body'] = {
  settings: {
    index: {
      number_of_shards: '2',
      number_of_replicas: '2',
      mapping: {
        total_fields: {
          limit: 10000,
        },
      },
    },
  },
```

and that gives me the message that `Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'mapping' does not exist in type 'IndicesIndexSettings'.` How can I set the total_fields limit using nodejs Elasticsearch client?

Answer (score 1):

I may be late to the party but here is a way to set the "index.mapping.total_fields.limit" at the index creation.

```
export const defaultCaseSettingsIndexConfig: IndicesCreateRequest["body"] = {
  settings: {
     ...,
    "index.mapping.total_fields.limit": "10000",
  },
};
```

Here is another example using Elastisearch js client.

```
const indexSettings = {
  settings: {
    ...,
    "index.mapping.total_fields.limit": "10000",
  },
};
this.client.indices.create({
  index: "my-index",
  body: indexSettings,
  ...
});
```